# Remove duplicate entries and keey the last one

Tags: php

First off I want to thank you for your help in advance.

I have an array structured like this:

```
array(18) {
  ["department"]=>
  string(14) "Administration"
  ["employee"]=>
  string(13) "Joe Smith"
  ["times"]=>
  string(6) "7:00am"
  ["timee"]=>
  string(6) "7:00pm"
  ["regular"]=>
  int(8)
  ["overtime"]=>
  int(4)
  ["d_overtime"]=>
  int(4)
  ["total"]=>
  int(12)
  ["cost"]=>
  int(28)
  ["date"]=>
  string(12) "May 27, 2014"
  ["curdp"]=>
  int(28)
  ["mtddp"]=>
  int(28)
  ["rev"]=>
  string(10) "35073.8900"
  ["dp2rev"]=>
  string(5) "0.08%"
  ["mtd2rev2013"]=>
  string(4) "-na-"
  ["mtdpay2rev"]=>
  string(5) "0.08%"
  ["budget"]=>
  string(4) "1.80"
  ["counter"]=>
  NULL
}
```

I need to be able to to find the very last entry in a array that has the same "date" value. For instance, I need to find all May 27,2014 values in the array and display the very last entry.

Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let input data is in $data

```
$resultArr = array();
$filteredByDateArr = array();

    foreach($data as $entry)
    {    
if($entry['date']=='May 27, 2014')
    $resultArr[] = $entry;

$filteredByDateArr[$entry['date']][] = $entry;

    }

    //last entry
    var_dump($resultArr[count($resultArr)-1]);
var_dump($filteredByDateArr);

//This $filteredByDateArr is the array that will give you date respective data.
//So if you want to find the last entry of say any date $date

//You can get it by:

var_dump($filteredByDateArr[$date][count($filteredByDateArr[$date])-1]);
```

Comment: Thanks for such a quick answer. I think this would work, however how would I make the =='May 27, 2014' dynamic if I did not know what to filter by? The array is composed up of many different date results. Would I have to filter for each day of the month?

Comment: Why are you building an array if you're only going to use the last value?

Comment: Jack - the section that I am showing is a piece of the array. It will have many different dates and times and the end result would be displayed on the screen like this:

Date     other value 1    other value 2   etc.